# Is it possible to use Blazer (Rails) as a standalone app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a backend in nodejs.
I found the Blazer demo very useful and more practical than apache superset (which I am using for now).
Do you think it is possible to use Blazer as standalone app? If so, I will learn ruby on rails to do it.

Comment: simple answer: yes